# Convert Mobile Web into Native Apllication Using WebView/phoneGap

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am gonna develop a mobile application for multiple devices, say iPhone, iPad and Android Devices like Samsung Galaxy,  Samsung Tab and Samsung Galaxy Nexus,

The application is about listing set of information from webservice to list in the application, So I decided to go for Mobile Web app using jquery mobile,

I want to publish the app in Appstore and Android Market, So I want to wrap the Mobile web in to a Native app, I thought an idea of implementing it in a UIWebView in iOS and WebView in Android,

Another option I found out is phoneGap,which provide an SDk to wrap an Web app into a Native iOS or Android App.

Can you people suggest me , Is it better to go with WebView in your native application, or is it really required to use phoneGap, Whether apple will approve my Application if I am using Mobile Web app in a UIWebView, Kindly Suggest.

Note: In my application there is no real need of Using any native functionality of iOS like, Camera, Contacts etc, I just wanna have a list with information fetched from the Webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any of the native features phonegap/callback gives you, do not use it. It's a bloated project that will probably add a ton of features you don't need, if you only need a wrapped web application.
Just use a regular webview, enable JS, caching etc and load your HTML into it.

Comment: does Apple app review process supports it?

Comment: Absolutely. there's a bunch of apps using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use phonegap. http://phonegap.com/  
If u use it you can use the phonegap build service to generate apps for all platforms via it. you will only have to worry about the js, html part of the app, like you said.
Or if you dont want to use the phonegap build, still creating your own apps with phonegap is way easier as you dont have to write ANY native code. 
There were some issues in Phonegap before because of which Apple was rejecting Phonegap apps previously. Thats fixed now, so thats no problem. :)

Comment: i suggested it because one doesn't need to write any native code while using phonegap. I mentioned that in the ans too. So even if one just knows js and html one can publish apps easily.